# Get current exchange token

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebrequest

I am having difficulty acquiring my current FaceBook exchange token.

Currently I can get a short term access token by using -

```
String OAuthURl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={MY-CLIENT-ID}&client_secret={MY-CLIENT-SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

Which brings back a response like -

```
123456789|ABCDEFGH
```

I am trying to generate a new long term access token by building the following URL-

```
String OAuthURl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={MY-CLIENT-ID}&client_secret={MY-CLIENT-SECRET}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token";
```

This brings back the response-

```
fb_exchange_token parameter not specified
```

So I tried -

```
String OAuthURl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={MY-CLIENT-ID}&client_secret={MY-CLIENT-SECRET}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=123456789|ABCDEFGH
```

However this is an invalid exchange token.

I believe the first URL I am trying is bringing back a `client_credentials` however how can I request my `fb_exchange_token` from a URL without having to manually go into my APP console?

Answer (score 1):

The first URL is requesting an application access token. Application access tokens can be used to modify application settings and perform some operations with users who have authorized your app. Application access tokens do not expire (unless you reset your app secret), and you do not need to exchange them for longer term tokens.

Comment: Yes, so how can I acquire my current fb_exchange_token using a URL?

Comment: The fb_exchange_token call is used to convert a current short term user access token into a long term user access token. You need to pass it a current short term user access token in the fb_exchange_token parameter. You can get a short term user access token through any of Facebook's [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/](login methods).

Comment: But as you can see in my question, the first url is doing exactly this, returning a short term access token, then the third posted URL appends this short term access token to the end of the request URL.

Comment: The first URL is returning an application access token, NOT a short term access token. Application access tokens do not expire and do not need to be exchanged.

Comment: OK, the link you have posted leads to nothing could you possibly update? If I can squire an access token as you say then I'll mark as correct. Also can you tell me the request URL to squire the said short term access token without manually going to the graph?

Comment: Whoops, I messed up that syntax earlier. You need to use one of Facebook's [login methods](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/). It's not just a URL that you can retrieve from your server, you have to implement the full Facebook login flow. You probably want to use the Javascript SDK to handle Facebook login and then pass the access token to your server to be extended and stored.